# Angular JS - Service returning function code as opposed to function return value

Tags: angularjs, service

I think I have a syntax error in my code, but I am not entirely sure. Basically when I call a function on the service, it returns the code rather than the return value of the function.

This is the service ...

```
(function (){
'use strict';

var products = function($http){

    var getProducts = function () {
        return $http.get(getDataUrl)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    };

    //Make functions public
    return {
        getProducts: getProducts
    };
};

var module = angular.module("shop");
module.factory("products", products);
module.constant("getDataUrl", "xxx")

}());
```

This is the controller than invokes the product service ...

```
 (function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module("shop")
    .controller("ProductController", ProductController);

function ProductController($scope, cart, $routeParams, products) {

    // $scope.product = products.getProducts;
    // console.log($scope.product);

    var productId = getProductIdFromUrl();
    console.log("productId: " + productId);

    console.log("products: " + products.getProducts);

    function getProductIdFromUrl(){
        return $routeParams.productId;
    }

}

})();
```

Now rather than returning the JSON data that I am expecting, the console.log is just printing the the functions code. Anyone any ideas?

The console.log prints the following ...

```
 products: function () {
        return $http.get(getDataUrl)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Yep, you do have a syntax error, right here:

```
console.log("products: " + products.getProducts);
```

That should be:

```
console.log("products: " + products.getProducts());
```

**HOWEVER** that is not going to log a list of products, it's going to log a promise object, which is what `$http.get().then()` returns. You need to re-read the documentation for `$http` and also read more about promises and how they work. Your code is non-functional as-is. This article explains why: http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/